# Autorización de usuarios (por roles) en Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

saludos desde Argentina.

Estoy empezando a aprender sobre Google Cloud Platform (GCP), y tengo la siguiente duda/necesidad.
Suponiendo que tenga un frontend deployado en algún container de Kubernetes en GCP, y a esa wep app necesite implementar autorización en los usuarios (para que tengan diferentes permisos), me gustaría saber cúal es la forma más óptima de hacerlo para GCP.
En otros proyectos he tenido la experiencia de usar Keycloak. Pero no se si realmente es la mejor solución.
Posiblemente intente usar el Single Sign On de Google, para facilitar el registro de los usuarios, por ejemplo usando Firebase Authentication.
Además agregar que el backend de esta web app es en realidad Firebase, siendo usado como base de datos. Por ahora es eso solamente lo que tengo en mente.

Tal vez encuentren cosas para corregir en como estoy planteando el uso de estas tecnologías, siéntanse libres de corregir, y desde ante mano gracias por las opiniones.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase es una excelente herramienta para autorizar a tus usuarios, y se complementa perfectamente con GCP, después si hablamos de permisos, accesos o roles, no te vas a salvar de tener una base de datos, la forma óptima la define la arquitectura de tu desarrollo, y es independiente de GCP, por ejemplo para una arquitectura serverless puedes implementar directamente en el front "Access Control List" (ACL), puedes usar Firestore como base, guardas el id correspondiente a Firebase Auth y sus privilegios de usuario, luego en el front ejecutarías 2 llamadas una para ver si esta autorizado y otra para obtener los permisos.

Comment: Gracias Adamo por tu información, la verdad que me sirve para investigar un poco más, sobre todo de ACL que no tengo idea que es, lo vi por ahí en Loopback ahora que estoy haciendo algo con ese framework. Soluciones serverless la verdad es algo nuevo para mi también, me estoy introduciendo en eso, lo tendré en cuenta para profundizar un poco más, gracias por tu comentario. Saludos :)